# Nodejs script to generate oath2 token for ansible tower

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, ansible, ansible-tower

How to write a node js script to generate oauth2 token for ansible tower.
Through cli :

```
curl -u username:password -k -X POST https://<tower-host>/api/v2/tokens/
```

Answer (score 0):

using axios (`npm i axios`) the script is:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var https = require('https');

const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
});

(async () => {
  var response = await instance({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api/v2/token',
    auth: { username: 'foo', password: 'bar' }
  });
  console.log('response is', response.data);
})();
```

[agent explanation](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535)